# Java 9 JDK webview is not showing openlayers map properly

Tags: java, javafx, webview, openlayers

So I used java jdk 9.0.4 for my project so that I could use j phoenix library on my javafx project. I created a web page with openlayers So that I could show map on my javafx application with the help of webview. But the webview is shrinking the map of the web page and the open layers cursor is shifted to the left. But the same fxml works for the JDK 1.8.0_241. I don't know what is causing the problem. Some one please help.....

Here is the picture of the webview on JDK 9.0.4
[9.0.4 JDK webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0b66.png)

And Here is the picture of the webview on jdk 1.8.0_241
[1.8.0_241 JDK webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY8qw.png)

And here is the html built with open layers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Draw Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lat=null;
        var lon=null;
        function getLat(){
            return lat;
        }
        function getLng(){
            return lng;
        }
        var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source,
            style: new ol.style.Style({

                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 8,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'red'
                    })
                })
            })
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, vector],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([90.4125,23.8103]),
                zoom: 15
            })
        });
        var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: source});
        map.addInteraction(modify);
        var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: source,
                type: "Point"
        });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
        map.on('contextmenu', function(evt){
            remove();

            var coords = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
            lat = coords[1];
            lon = coords[0];
            var locTxt = "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon;
        });
        function remove(){
            var features = source.getFeatures();
            var lastFeature = features[features.length-1];
            source.clear();
            console.log(lastFeature);
            source.addFeature(lastFeature);
        }
        map.on('click', function(evt){
            remove();
            var coords = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
            lat = coords[1];
            lon = coords[0];
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the java controller code

```
package sample;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author MeawMeawPotatoChips
 */
public class PostController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private WebView postWebView;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        postWebView.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        postWebView.getEngine().load("http://localhost/map/setaddress.php?key=cse299&lng=90.4125&lat=23.8103");
    }    

}
```

And Finally the FXML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="637.0" prefWidth="825.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.241" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.PostController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="postWebView" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="128.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="33.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="22.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="185.0" />
   </children>
   <effect>
      <DropShadow />
   </effect>
</AnchorPane>
```